# Closing broken connection

Tags: .net, serial-port

I have a VB.NET application which periodically communicates with some device over the Bluetooth (`System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` is used). Periodically means that the application sends requests to the device in 1 second interval.

Everything works perfectly (opening/closing connection, data sending/receiving) but there is one usecase which I do not know to handle properly. The usecase is when the connection is broken (device has been turned off, battery has died, devices has been moved out of a range...).

There is no way how to find out if the connection is broken using .NET. I decide that the connection is broken if the device has not sent a response to 5 my requests. Then I run this code:

```
Try
    If (sp.IsOpen) Then sp.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    ' do something
End Try
```

Of course that the property `IsOpen` returns `true` even if the connection is broken because it has been disconnected physically and `SerialPort` changes the property only after calling `Close()`. So `sp.Close()` is executed but it of course fires the IOException (*No process is on the other end of the pipe*). It is OK, it is handled by `Try-Catch`.

The problem is that when the application is trying to close the connection, it freezes for a few seconds and then if fires the exception. Is there a way how to check if the connection is broken to avoid freezing the application? It does not seem to me to be a best solution to make a separated thread for closing. My opinion is that I should check state of a serial port... Thanks

Comment: Your problem is pretty mild compared to what can happen in a case like this.  Plenty of drivers around that throw an uncatchable exception when you try to close a port that no longer exists.  The answer is already in your question, you already know that the connection is dead by trying 5 times to get a response.  No point in calling Close(), it doesn't make it better.  So just set a *bool* flag and if it still makes sense to keep your program running (unusual) then limp along without it.

Comment: You are right. I do not know why but I thought I must use Close() method at any cost. Just set a flag that the connection is closed if I do not get response 5 times in row and that's it. Thanks